# Return list element by the value of one of its attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a list of objects

```
l = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

Each `obj` is an object of a class and has an `id` attribute.

How can I return an `obj` from the list by its `id`?

P.S. `id`s are unique. and it is guaranteed that the list contains an object with the requested `id`

Comment: are `id`s unique, is it for sure that one of the objs has the `id` you want?

Comment: `myobj = next(x for x in l if x.id==myid)`

Comment: FWIW, all Python objects already have a unique id, which you can obtain with the [built-in `id` function](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#id). In CPython (aka standard Python) the id is the memory address of the object. Of course, that id may not be suitable for your use case because it changes each time the program runs. And if an object is destroyed its id can be recycled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the `id` is a hashable object, like a string, you should be using a dictionary, not a list.

```
l = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
d = {o.id:o for o in l}
```

You can then retrieve objects with their keys, e.g. `d['ID_39A']`.

Comment: Ok.I agree. I only thought that maybe there is a simple way of doing it, which i didn't see. Dictionary works far better here. And for now i do not see any drawbacks of using it within my code

Comment: Assuming you did want to go over the list though, you could do `obj, = (obj for obj in l if obj.id == 'whatever')` you'll also have the bonus of getting a `ValueError` if there isn't exactly one match.

Comment: @NinjaPuppy Yeah, already did this at some point in my code.  I think the initial choice of a list (as opposed to dictionary) - was a poor choice :)

Comment: I like rules of thumb :)